# Can we use Pyomo for goal programming using python

Tags: pyomo

I am working on building an inventory management system having multiple objectives like price, lead time, quality, etc and want to use goal programming. Wanted to know if we can use Pyomo for implementing goal programming

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: Yes it's possible, you just have to model your goals and the deviations as variables you want to minimize.